# addSparkListener equivalent in databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, listener, databricks

I want to register custom SparkListener with Databricks' spark context.

With basic spark i can just use *"spark.jars"* and *"spark.extraListeners"* configs during spark-submit. OR use *sparkContext.addSparkListener* api.

For databricks setup,I have installed the jar containing listener on my cluster. When I put the config "spark.extraListeners" in "advanced" config tab of the cluster, cluster fails to initialize throwing error Listener not found.

I tried setting it during sparksession builder like

```
    .builder \
    .appName("abc") \
    .config("spark.extraListeners","mySparkListener") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()
```

databricks wont add it. No errors thrown but listener is not added.

Is there any way to do this?
Note: I am using python notebooks on databricks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you get into the notebook, `SparkSession` is already initialized, so your configuration doesn't have an effect.

You need to have this setting specified when cluster is starting - you did it correctly by specifying in the cluster Spark conf settings, but the problem is that libraries are installed after Spark is started, and necessary classes aren't found.  You can fix this by adding a [cluster init script](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/init-scripts.html), something like this - you need to have you library installed somewhere on DBFS (I use `/FileStore/jars/my_jar.jar` as an example):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cp /dbfs/FileStore/jars/my_jar.jar /databricks/jars
```

this script will copy your jar file into the directory with jars on the local disk, and this will happen before Spark starts.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution worked liked a charm. Saved me lot of time.